# What is the meaning of the expression "sling a yarn"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I am quoting from *[The Return of Sherlock Holmes, Black Peter](https://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/178/the-return-of-sherlock-holmes/3232/chapter-vi-the-adventure-of-black-peter/)*:

> See here, mister, said he, I make no complaint of being man-handled in this fashion, but I would have you call things by their right names. You say I murdered Peter Carey; I say I killed Peter Carey, and there’s all the difference. Maybe you don’t believe what I say. Maybe you think I am just ***slinging you a yarn***.

It seems from the context that it means that the speaker (Patrick Cairns) meant that he is not making up the story but I couldn't find any entry for the entire expression in any dictionary although there are many for the word 'yarn' which mean 'a tale' or 'an untrue story'.

Comment: "**spinning** a yarn" is a common expression. Perhaps it's an OCR misreading of "Maybe you think I'm just spinning you a yarn."

Comment: It's defined in [encyclo.co.uk](https://www.encyclo.co.uk/meaning-of-Sling_A_Yarn).

Comment: It means "Maybe you think I'm lying to you". The phrase "tell a story" can always refer to making up a story instead of telling the truth.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian "spinning a yarn" is a literal process in textile production as well as the metaphorical invention of a story

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The expression is of nautical origin and dates to the beginning of 19th c.

***[yarn](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/jxsdseq)*** n.

> [the stories told by sailors during the lengthy processes of making ropes; note Hall Caine, The Deemster (1897): ‘Without motive a story is not a novel, but only a yarn’: in other words, a yarn implies the dichotomy between ‘literary’ and ‘popular’ writing] (orig. naut.)
>
> 1. a story, esp. a long and poss. implausibly wonderful one.
>
> - 1821   [UK]    J. Burrowes Life in St George’s Fields 13: You see what a tough yarn the Doctor was spinning.

***[sling a yarn](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/jxsdseq#7y26dja) (v.)*** [sling v. (2a)](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/augpiha#sn2a)

> to tell a story.

> - 1876    [US]    B. Harte Gabriel Conroy II 302: Well, you jess stands up afore the jedge, and you slings ’em a yarn.
> - 1889    [Aus]   H. Lawson ‘The Sleeping Beauty’ in Roderick (1967–9) I 57: I’ll sling you a yarn worth more nor two / Such pumped-up yarns as that.

(Green’s Dictionary of Slang)

Comment: I should've checked Green! +1

Comment: Definitely more accurate reference than what I have found. Well deserved +1.

Answer (score 5):

***Sling a yarn*** is slang for:

> ***to relate a story***: C.20: s. >, ca. 1930, coll. Cf. sling language, q.v.—2. Hence, ***to tell a lie***: 1904 (*[A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IAjyQdFwh4UC&pg=PA1088&lpg=PA1088&dq=%22sling%20a%20yarn%22&source=bl&ots=_4QAkIuO_I&sig=ACfU3U2hNRMYg0ZPsFe0Is3W-guB0AxWVQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFmqKrtuL8AhVjQEEAHUn2AuIQ6AF6BAgbEAM)*, Eric Partridge · 2006)

This seems to be a usage particular to Sir Conan Doyle. This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=slinging%20you%20a%20yarn&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) will show a striking increase in usage after the year 2000, and when you look at the hits in Google Books, they are all from commentaries on this passage. See the hits from [2018 to 2019](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22slinging%20you%20a%20yarn%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2018,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en), for example.

Comment: It's interesting that Eric Partridge's only example is the one mentioned in the question! Maybe Conan Doyle coined it/made a mistake.

Comment: Interesting. I don't know a lot about Conan Doyle's use of slang, but it's not uncommon for writers either to make up slang or to use variations. *Sling* has various slang meanings, from selling drugs (which is might be more recent) to its use in cocktails, which seems to precede the [Singapore Sling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_sling) (gin sling) of 1915.

Comment: In fact it's a **hapax legomenon**! It _only_ appears in the Conan Doyle story. Doyle either invented it or, more likely, just got 'spinning a yarn' wrong! And Eric Partridge was easily fooled! :-)

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I doubt that such a prolific author would make a mistake. Coyle is quirky in his expressions, he probably twisted the expression for his own purpose.

Comment: @StuartF In informal BE _sling_ can also mean [_to throw or drop something carelessly_](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sling) or casually.

Comment: That's three misleading comments I've made. I rest. :-)

Comment: What @OldBrixtonian said. Perhaps Conan Doyle was conflating *You're **spinning** me a yarn!* (Which I don't believe) with ***Sling** yer hook!* (Go away - I don't want to listen to you).

Comment: @fev I feel like the opposite logic makes more sense.  Him being prolific means that he had more chances for a mistake to be in something he published.  Writing a lot wouldnt make you infallible.